# How to use a certificate with pac4j jwt?

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I have an existing REST service which I want to secure with JWT. I also want to use spring security. I stumbled upon pac4j, which looks very modular und promising. They have libs for jwt (pac4j-jwt) and an integration with spring secuity (spring-security-pac4j). I just dont know how to use an public key from a PEM file to validate the JWT. I only see the possibility to pass the public key as a string. The public key from the service consumer looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
base64encodedString
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Can I just read the file from a keystore and substring the base64 encoded string und use it for validation? Is there an easier way?